# Pyspark and Cassandra Connection Error

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I have stucked with a problem. When i write sample cassandra connection code while import cassandra connector gives error.

i am starting the script like below code (both of them gave error)

```
./spark-submit --jars spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-1.6.0-M1.jar /home/beyhan/sparkCassandra.py

./spark-submit --jars spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.6.0.jar /home/beyhan/sparkCassandra.py
```

But giving below error while

```
import pyspark_cassandra
```

> ImportError: No module named pyspark_cassandra

Which part i did wrong ?

Note:I have already installed cassandra database.

Comment: Where did you get that import statement from? Have read you the Cassandra connector's documentation: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#documentation? That import statement is not mentioned anywhere, because indeed there is no module with that name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up DataStax' Spark Cassandra Connector (in the jar you add to spark submit), and TargetHolding's PySpark Cassandra project (which has the `pyspark_cassandra` module). The latter is deprecated, so you should probably use the Spark Cassandra Connector. Documention for this package can be found [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#documentation).

To use it, you can add the following flags to spark submit:

```
--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 \
--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3
```

Of course use the IP address on which Cassandra is listening, and check what connector version you need to use: 2.0.0-M3 is the latest version and works with Spark 2.0 and most Cassandra versions. See the [compatibility table](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) in case you are using a different version of Spark. `2.10` or `2.11` is the version of Scala your Spark version is built with. If you use Spark 2, by default it is 2.11, before 2.x it was version 2.10.

Then the nicest way to work with the connector is to use it to read dataframes, which looks like this:

```
 sqlContext.read\
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
  .options(table="kv", keyspace="test")\
  .load().show()
```

See the [PySpark with DataFrames](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md) documentation for more details